# How to scroll page elements with the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I basically want to achieve the same effect as in Google Reader: when you press "j", you are pushed down to the next article and when you press "k", you can go back up to the previous article. What is the simplest way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Using `onkeyup` and use the `keyCode` to determine the key pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/gzRwN/1/.

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode;
    if(code === 74) { // key code for j
        window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft,
                        document.body.scrollTop + 500);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have this: <div class="photo"><img src="1.jpg"/></div>

What would I have to change so that every time somebody pushes "j" or "k", they're redirected to the next or previous div with the same class?

Answer (score -1):

Get the number/value for those keys and bind them to the event that you'd like them to execute. Much in the way that a `click` would be used to fire a function, but instead you're using a certain key.

Comment: include some code or link to an example to improve this answer.